# Bad Request Error (400) in json while posting to restful api in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am getting the below error while sending post request ,

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"No of Planet names has to
>   be 4\"}\n","responseJSON":{"error":"No of Planet names has to be
>   4"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}

**My code**

```
var myPlanets=['Sapir','Jebing','Enchai','Pingasor'];
var myVehicles=['Space rocket','Space rocket','Space rocket','Space rocket'];

$(function()
{
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/find',
    headers:{
        Accept:'application/json',
    },

    data:JSON.stringify({key:"keyToken", myPlanets:"myPlanets",myVehicles:"myVehicles"}),                  

    success:function(status){
        alert('success');     
    },

    error:function(status){
        alert(JSON.stringify(status));
    }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of stringifying the fields is incorrect as it points myPlanets to the string "myPlanets" instead of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It probably because you aren't sending any data to the API. In your data attribute's value, you have written like `key: "keyToken"` which sends the string "keyToken" to the API. Instead if you intend to send the value of a variable, send it like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  key: keyToken,
  myPlanets: myPlanets,
  myVehicles: myVehicles // Note that I've removed quotes
})
```

Comment: Hello ,thankyou a lot.I have changed in the way you said.But still displays the same error.

Comment: That's not a technical error. It has something to do with the logic of the API. You should post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

while, the page is 404.

and try again with

`headers:{
    Accept:'*/*',
},`

Comment: "readyState":4,"responseText":"404 page not found\n","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"} is occuring now, after changing code to '*/* .

Comment: [your website](https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/) 404, your js code cannot fixed it...